# Are there action hooks for comments?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, hooks, actions

This is for a personal-use plugin I'm trying to make. I want to submit a comment from site A to my blog (sort of like sending trackbacks/pingbacks but a full comment).

For instance, on site A I have a form with a name, url, and comment field. The data I enter in site A, I want to submit to site B (my blog) via URL parameters or the POST method.

I assume that I'll need an action hook on my blog to retrieve data sent from site A and insert it in the wp comment table.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WordPress, almost anything is possible. It all depends at times how hard you want to work for it. :)

The Comment Post form of course uses HTTP POST to submit to `/wp-comments-post.php` so you could use that except for the [NONCEs](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) if you want to post unfiltered HTML. You'd have to write a page to give you an acceptable NONCE which Site A would need to HTTP GET in order to be able to submit back to to the comment post form but I think if you don't mind the filters it should work fine.

Another option is to use a function [designed for AJAX](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax) but have it capture your HTTP POST from your form and then save your comment to Site B by calling `wp_insert_comment()`. Or you could use AJAX on Site B to talk to Site A. Of course you'll be opening up a bit of a security hole by doing that, but if your code isn't distributed you can decide if that creates a real concern or not.

*(Normally I would write up an example but have run out of time today. Hopefully the above sends you in the right direction.)*

Comment: MikeSchinkel thank you for the reply! You definably put me on the right track :)I'll post an example soon and see if it's anything close to what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I put together an example. I hope it will work :)

**Passing data from site A to site B (the blog):**

On site A I think I'll use the POST method, to send data to site B. I don't wan't to pass parameters in the url.

And on site B, I'll have

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$time = current_time('mysql');

$data = array(
    'comment_author' => $name,
    'comment_author_email' => $email,
    'comment_author_url' => $url,
    'comment_content' => $content,
    'comment_date' => $time,
    'comment_approved' => 1,
);

wp_insert_comment($data);
```